# create a website uptime monitor in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a uptime monitor using NodeJS and MongoDB. I want to run a cron job in NodeJS and store the data into MongoDB. If the website response status code is not equal to `200` then it will be saved in the database. I want to make a database entry like this,

```
url : http://www.google.com
status_code : 500
start_time :- start time
end_time :- end time
```

I can run the cron job but not sure how to save the downtime in the database. As, I don't want to store every response into the database. Only when response status code is other than `200` , then it will start tracking (`start_time`) the URL and it keeps the time when website is back to `200` as `end_time`.

`cron.js` :-

```
var async=require('async');
const Entry = require('../models/health.model.js');

var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests () {

    Entry.find({},function(err,entrys){
      console.log(err);
      if(!err && entrys){

         async.each(entrys,function(entry,callback){


           request(entry.url, function (error, response, body) {
            entry.statuscheck=response.statusCode;
            entry.save();
            callback();
            });


         },function (error) {

         });

      }
    });

}
```

`health.model.js` :-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const EntrySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    url: String,
    statuscheck: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Entry', EntrySchema);
```

Comment: Why would you do this rather than using an existing uptime monitor?  I don't mean that confrontationally; I mean it to try and extract what's different about what you're trying to do from what existing solutions do.

Comment: Well @paul, I'm not saying I agree with the layout of this as it has no notifications, but honestly this type of functionality can be built pretty easily (ping a site and see if there are errors), other solutions (and I use Uptime Monitor currently) cost money for even 50 monitors. You can deploy on a $5/month server on Digital Ocean and monitor as many sites as you want as often as wanted. This seems like a better option in my opinion currently because they are simple monitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this to handle updating the database. I went ahead and put standard arrow functions in, because it was easier for me that way. I put some comments in so that should clear most questions up. It may not be the most elegant solution because I wrote it in 5 minutes, but if you follow this general logic flow, you should be much closer to your solution (its completely untested mind you.)

```
var async=require('async');
const Entry = require('../models/health.model.js');

var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function getHttpsRequests () {
  Entry.find({}, (err,entrys) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (!err && entrys) {
      async.each(entrys, (entry,callback) => {
        request(entry.url, (error, response, body) => {
          //first check if the url has a document in the db.
          Entry.find({ url: entry.url }, (err, entry) => {
            if(!entry) {
              //since the document does not exist, check the statusCode.
              if(response.statusCode===200) { //if the statusCode is 200, continue the loop.
                callback();
              } else { //if the status code is not 200, lets save this to the db.
                console.log("Saving object: " + entry)
                entry.status_code = response.statusCode;
                entry.start_time = new Date();
                entry.save();
                callback();
              }
            } else if (entry) {
              //since the document exists, lets check the statusCode.
              if(response.statusCode===200) { //if the statusCode is 200, update the stop_time.
                entry.end_time = new Date();
                Entry.findOneAndUpdate({ url: entry.url }, entry, (err, object) => { //this returns the entry after update, so we can put that in the console for easy debug.
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback();
                  } else {
                    console.log("Object saved: " + object);
                    callback();
                  }
                });
              }
            } else { //there was an error finding the document in the db, just go to the next one.
              callback();
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea.